# Azure Functions in JavasScript/TypeScript: How to DI?

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I've seen a lot of tutorials and questions asking how to do DI in .NET for Azure Functions, but none for JavaScript or TypeScript.

How would one go about providing different implementations to Azure Functions?

Comment: You can refer to [Dependency Injection in JavaScript 101](https://dev.to/azure/dependency-injection-in-javascript-101-2b1e), [Dependency Injection Explained via JavaScript](https://blog.jeremylikness.com/blog/2014-06-28_dependency-injection-explained-javascript/) and [As of now Dependency Injection for Java is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69397058/azure-serverless-java-rest-api-not-sharing-singleton-objects/69403865#69403865)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for multiple blogs where we can understand about DI in JavaScript as DeepDave suggested.

You can refer to this [GIT blog](https://github.com/jakkaj/EnterpriseAzureFunctions#injectable-composable-testable-typescript-azure-functions) where we can find the project about Injectable Type script azure functions.
Below is the sample constructor on TypeScript based:

```
constructor(@inject(contracts.contractSymbols.ICognitiveService) cognitiveService:contracts.ICognitiveService) {
        super();
        this._cognitiveService = cognitiveService;
    }
```